# Django : Iterating over data

Tags: python, django

I am having a variable `cc` in which I getting data from session:

```
cc = request.session['cc_list']
```

and the data is in this format :

```
[
{"model": "InBound.challengecode", "pk": 1, "fields": {"challenge_code": 50, 
"sve_challenge_text": "Good"}}, 
{"model": "InBound.challengecode", "pk": 2, "fields": {"challenge_code": 48, 
"sve_challenge_text": "Voter Not Signed"}}
]
```

Now I want to know how to iterate over it and get values of `challenge_code` and `sve_challenge_text` as whenever I iterate over its starts iterating by characters like `'[', '{', '"'.....`.

And I am setting data into session as :

```
class ViewChallengeCodes(PermissionRequiredMixin, ExportMixin, SingleTableView):
model = ChallengeCode
table_class = ChallengeCodesTable
permission_required = ('InBound.list_challenge',)
table_pagination = {'per_page': 20}

def get_queryset(self):
    challenge_code = super().get_queryset().filter(project__record_status=BaseModel.RecordActive).exclude(record_status=BaseModel.RecordDeleted)
    cc_list = serializers.serialize('json', list(challenge_code), fields=('challenge_code', 'sve_challenge_text'))

    self.request.session['cc_list'] = cc_list

    return challenge_code
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your attempt so far?

Comment: And how is this data getting into the session in the first place?

Comment: Hi just updated the code of setting data into session.

Comment: This looks like you're iterating over a `string`. Maybe you don't get a `json` response but a `string`. Therefore `json.loads(your_data)` might help.

Comment: @Igle thanks, it worked for me

Comment: Or don't serialize to a string in the first place.

Comment: Please answer your question and close it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37752/how-do-i-close-my-own-question